# Attaching multiple images to User Model using Arc and Arc.Ecto

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to create an API for image upload and download. I'm using Arc for image upload(local storage) and Arc.Ecto for attaching the uploaded image with the User Model. 
API allows user to upload multiple images. When I upload different images Arc successfully saves each image against the user.

My question is, How can I upload multiple images and store those image reference in the DB as well. Currently Arc keeps replacing the same image reference.

```
  schema "users" do
    field :name, :string
    field :age, :integer
    field :gender, :string
    field :user_name, :string
    field :email, :string
    field :crypted_password, :string
    field :password, :string, virtual: true
    field :avatar, LoginService.Avatar.Type
    timestamps
  end
```

I tried creating multiple fields in the User model with **MyApp.Avatar.Type** type to store images, But I can't find the connection **where I can tell arc to store a given image on that particular user field**.
For example I want to save first image against the "avatar" field in the User Model and then save the second image against the "image_1" field against the same user model.

My Upload Method on controller:

```
def upload(conn, user_params) do
  case get_user(conn) do
     {:ok, scope}  ->
                     changeset = User.changeset(scope, user_params)
                     case Repo.update(changeset) do
                         {:ok, scope} ->  case Avatar.store({user_params["avatar"],scope}) do
                                                   {:ok, file} ->
                                                     send_resp(conn, :no_content, "")
                                                   {:error, error} -> send_resp(conn, 500, "")
                                                 end
                       {:error, changeset} ->  send_resp(conn, :unprocessable_entity, changeset)
                   end
      {:ok, reasons} -> conn |> json(%{error: "failed to save image", reasons: reasons})
              end
  end
```

So when I say Avatar.store({user_params["avatar"],scope}) in the above method, Arc stores the image in a local directory and saves the image name plus version in the avatar field in the user model.

and request is:

```
POST localhost:4000///api/documents
```

Body: `{"avatar": "/Users/xyz/Documents/abc/wed-7.jpg"}`

Comment: Well, I haven't really used Arc but I think you can easily learn what's happening in the source code and that may help, also you dont want to have multiple columns like `image`, `image_1` and so on, it's way better to just create another table, like `images` and whatnot and make it "belong" to the user model. Or you could put only the image's basename into a database record and then version the files, like `thumb_basename`, `original_basename` etc

Answer (score 0):

If you establish a certain structure and regular path to each user, then you just need to append the filename at the end of each path (inside the same folder for each user) and you'll have many images for each user.

In my project I did this in the Elixir file generated by arc, inside the following function:

```
  def storage_dir(_, {_file, scope}) do
    "/uploads/tickets/attachments/#{scope.id}"
  end
```

You shouldn't be inserting an image into the user model directly. If you want to store the images by user I recommend doing a user_images table, where for each image, you store the user's id and the images URL (and other fields you may want).